# Checking for a common base of two modular exponentiations with different moduli

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

Given following equations

$a=m^{e_1}\mod n_1\\$

$b=m^{e_2}\mod n_2$

if you know the values of $a$, $b$ and all variables except for $m$, is it always possible to efficiently verify that the value of $m$ used to calculate $b$ was the same as the one used to calculate $a$?

If $n_1=n_2=n$ you could compute $a^{e_2}\mod n=b^{e_1}\mod n=m^{e_1e_2}\mod n$. However, if $n_1\neq n_2$, this does not work.

Comment: Do we know the factorization of $n_1$  and $n_2$?

Comment: No we don't know it.

Comment: Odd mod odd depends on multiplier of modulus.

Comment: Remember that, $e$th modulus is hard if the factorization is not known. What is the origin of this question?